# Target on genymotion

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

How to set the target on genymotion emulator like this (Google APIs)?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Google APIs equivalent images for Genymotion. If your app needs anything that is not in vanilla AOSP, then you need to install all the Google Apps (like Google Play Services etc) separately.